# master detail binding in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Why don't I see the details in this example.  I cannot change the structure of dataclass, master class and detail class. So I have to solve this with the correct binding.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public dataclass data { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        data = new dataclass();
        master a_master = new master();
        a_master.mastername = "hello";
        detail a_detail = new detail();
        a_detail.detailname = "goodbye";
        data.details.Add(a_detail);
        data.Add(a_master);
    }
}


public class dataclass : ObservableCollection<master>
{
   public ObservableCollection<detail> details { get; set; }

    public dataclass()
    {
        details = new ObservableCollection<detail>();
    }
}


public class master
{
    public string mastername { get; set; }


}


public class detail
{
    public string detailname { get; set; }
}
```

And in my XAML I am binding like this:

```
<Window x:Class="md.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:md.viewmodels"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=data}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="master" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding mastername}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=data/details}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="detail" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding detailname}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
<ItemsSource="{Binding Path=data.details}">
```

instead of

```
<ItemsSource="{Binding Path=data/details}">
```

I think what you tried to achieve was kind of a master/detail scenario with binding to hierarchical data like decribed in [How to: Use the Master-Detail Pattern with Hierarchical Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742531.aspx). In fact, as long as you have an `ObservableCollection<details>` as property of a class derived from `ObservableCollection<master>` this is not hierarchical, and hence the `/` in the binding expression won't work. See [PropertyPath XAML Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451.aspx), section *Source Traversal (Binding to Hierarchies of Collections)* for details about the `/`.

Also there are widely accepted conventions for [capitalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx) in C#, saying that you should use Pascal casing for public types like the classes and properties here.

Comment: I can change this ofcourse. I just wanted to learn about my error in the binding. I my real application the master and detail are entity framework classes. In what would you load the data for the listviews to bind to if not nested observables?

Comment: In hierarchical data the `details` collection would be part of class `master`. See the edited answer for a link.